# implementing the REST way

Tags: rest

I did not realise the power of REST until I started using scaffolds in rails. This makes life so simple. Now everytime I try to develop a web application I only think of those 6 verbs. But I have a doubt. How is search related to REST. 
Basically the search page which contain a form for the user to input a search term.
which verb does this come under? Is it list??
and what does the search results come under? show?

Comment: Despite the terms Rails uses, that verb scaffolding has nothing to do with REST. It is simply a correct usage of HTTP. Necessary, but not at all sufficient for being RESTful.

Comment: HTTP query strings also have nothing to do with REST. Please remove the references/tags to REST from this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are saying properly, the search page wouldn't be a part of the rest service, but would submit to it.

The search results would be a list of whatever the first class object you had defined was. The Uri would describe the resource that was being displayed.

Retrieving resources is always done with a GET

eg: GET /cars?term=hyundai+green

Answer (score 6):

Search is GET on the collection with some fancy attributes:

```
GET /articles?q=RESFful+Architecture&in_title=1
```

Something like that.

There are plenty of resources on the subject, check out [Handling arbitrary actions](http://ajaxpatterns.org/RESTful_Service#Handling_arbitrary_actions), on ajaxpatterns, for example.